# Ubuntu Logs meaning Disconnected, Invalid user and etc. Server attack

Tags: server, sshd, logs

Recently installed new server, my first one and almost immediately started to receiving following log, it seems that someone is trying to access my server. 
Could not find a detailed description about these logs:

If someone can help to understand what each line mean:

```
sshd: Invalid user admin from 141.98.81.38 port 43680

sshd: Disconnected from invalid user admin 141.98.81.38 port 43680 [preauth]

sshd: Invalid user ubnt from 141.98.81.37 port 17284

sshd: Disconnected from authenticating user root 222.186.30.187 port 10607 [preauth]

sshd: error: Received disconnect from 141.98.81.37 port 17284:14: Unable to connect using the available authentication methods [preauth]

kernel: [19614.450491] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=4a:04:c8:bf:78:72:cc:e1:7f:a8:1b:f0:08:00 SRC=193.32.163.9 DST=167.1XX.XXX.XXX LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=245 ID=51394 PROTO=TCP SPT=51676 DPT=33399 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Comment: Your attackers appear to be from Panama, China, and Russia and they're using ssh to connect. Have you publically advertised your server, or it's address? Have you assured that you have good passwords for any/all accounts, and that all unnecessary ports are closed in your firewall?

Comment: The weird fact is that I have just published the server, I didn't even attached a domain. SSH is only accessible with ssh keys. I have not set the firewall yet, will be checking it today.

Comment: You can use a tool like fail2ban to block IPs automatically after a set number of failures. These are probably scripts that scan IPs looking for open 22 ports (ssh) and if you've deployed on a major service provider they are likely scanning those IP ranges already. I get these from time to time on my machines, I think they're pretty common. Good practice is to always disable root login and use only ssh keys (which it sounds like you already have setup) but it doesn't hurt to also use another layer like fail2ban. There are other tools too, but I've always found fail2ban easy to setup and config

Answer (score 2):

I feel like this is kinda normal. I recieve those attempts on many of machines. They usually try some very common usernames like: "pi", "admin", "ubuntu" or "teamspeak". My guess is, that they are just scanning for open ports on 22 to brute force over ssh. They are targeting users that use insecure passwords.

There are easy steps to avoid falling victim:

1. Install fail2ban and configure it to ban the IPs after 3 failed attempts for 24 hours. Just be careful to not lock yourself out.
2. Configure SSH to only accept public key authentication.
3. Don't allow root login over SSH.
4. Put SSH on some other port.

Answer (score 0):

SSH brute force attacks are not uncommon but usually fail if the config file is set to the defaults.  I connect to the Internet via a VPN which pretty much eliminates a great many exploit schemes.  This approach may not be practical in your application if your server's IP address must be visible to the Internet.  Placing your server on your router's DMZ and only allowing a small number of ports to be accessed (e.g. HTTPS, SSH) will help a lot.  Disabling any unnecessary services is also key.

There are many answers on this site explaining how to harden an sshd server.  The attack you are experiencing is trivial and a very bush league.  Doomed to fail unless you have removed any of the default safeguards.  Nothing especially to worry about here.  However, being visible to the Internet does put you at risk so you should be looking at the bigger picture here.  There are a lot of other exploits out there so you want to do everything possible to make yourself as invisible as possible to bad actors.

There are a few basic best practices that can really help you here including blocking access to all but a few critical ports via the firewall.  Disabling telnet and ftp.  The maximum login attempts default is 6 which is a reasonable setting.  Refer to `man sshd_config` for a full list of settings.

Tighten up sshd as follows:

```
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config

LoginGraceTime 30
port 2222
StrictModes yes
IgnoreRhosts yes
PermitRootLogin no
AllowUsers yourself
DenyUsers admin
```

Restart sshd:

```
systemctl restart sshd.service
```